# Spring-Security getRemoteAddress for app behind proxy

Tags: spring-security, proxy, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

Is there a reason why the Spring-Security dose not provide any possibility to lookup for the RemoteAddress when the application is located behind a proxy e.g. load balancer, apache httpd server? At the moment the *WebAuthenticationDetails* object is saving the ip of the proxy. I saw that there are also solution for finding the remote address over the *X-FORWARDED-FOR* header attribute. I am curios is a reason why this is not provided?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Tomcat, you could configure [RemoteIpValve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html).

> Tomcat port of `mod_remoteip`, this valve replaces the apparent client remote IP address and hostname for the request with the IP address list presented by a proxy or a load balancer via a request headers (e.g. "X-Forwarded-For").